# How can I export embedded documents from mongo with mongoexport to Excel(CSV)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I have a mongoDb collection of temperature sensor readings at various intervals.  There is a document that has the"id" of the temperature sensor, with a sensor owner "f", and a base reading date "d". Then we have an array of embedded documents the have 1) reading date/time "dt", 2) observation "obs", and 3) raw id "raw.

```
"{""id"":""f07550c4"",""f"":""xyz"",""d"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:00:00.000Z""}}","
[
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:00:39.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.429792429792428},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE171056E6558B1""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:01:37.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.460317460317462},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE171056FA49831""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:02:34.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.490842490842489},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE1710570E5502B""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:03:02.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.521367521367523},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE17105712490AB""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:03:31.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.521367521367523},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE17105712490AB""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:03:59.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.521367521367523},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE17105712490AB""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:04:28.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.55189255189255},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE17105726491ED""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:06:23.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.643467643467645},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE1710575255373""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:09:13.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.796092796092793},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE171057A6557BC""},
{""dt"":{""$date"":""2016-02-08T00:10:38.000Z""},""obs"":{""temp"":2.887667887667888},""raw"":""76F07550C4013FE171057D2495BC""}
]}
```

-- I am trying to export to an excel (csv) format for compliance auditing that would consist of the reading date, and observation result:

```
2016-02-08T00:00:39.000Z, 2.429792429792428
2016-02-08T00:01:37.000Z, 2.460317460317462
2016-02-08T00:02:34.000Z, 2.490842490842489
2016-02-08T00:03:02.000Z, 2.521367521367523
2016-02-08T00:03:31.000Z, 2.521367521367523
2016-02-08T00:03:59.000Z, 2.521367521367523
2016-02-08T00:04:28.000Z, 2.55189255189255
2016-02-08T00:06:23.000Z, 2.643467643467645
2016-02-08T00:09:13.000Z, 2.796092796092793
2016-02-08T00:10:38.000Z, 2.887667887667888
```

I have tried the following, but don't get any returned items besides the id.

```
mongoexport -d mymongo -c bkup --type=csv --query {\"_id.id\":\"f07550c4\"} --fields _id.id,archive.dt,archive.obs --out=events.csv
```

where "f07550c4" is the particular sensor I want the records for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please tell what is the operating system and the version of MongoDB.

Comment: I think there is no way to export an array of nested document with specific fields only . Common solution is to write an aggregation query which outputs the necessary fields into a staging collection from which you can run the export.